# spinner in android showing object id when clicking

Tags: android

I am new to android and trying to develop my college project, i am creating  spinner with custom adapter class which is extending Array Adapter when the program run it is showing spinner with the first category correctly but when i click on the spinner to see other entries it is showing object values screen shot is attach.

However on the onItemSelect method when i select any item and showing the entry in the Toast it is showing correctly.

any help will be highly appreciated.

[image: screenshot]

also please tell me how to select the category which is saved by user and i am already have that in my code.

here is the code from Activity class.

```
            mAdapter = new CityAdapter(this,R.id.citytitle , new 
            ArrayList<CitiesModel>());
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
            spinner.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            mAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.city_row);

 @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<CitiesModel>> loader, List<CitiesModel> cites) {

        mAdapter.clear();

        if(cites!=null && !cites.isEmpty()) {

            mAdapter.addAll(cites);


        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<CitiesModel>> loader) {


        mAdapter.addAll(new ArrayList<CitiesModel>());

    }


    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, 
    long id) {
        // On selecting a spinner item
        CitiesModel item = (CitiesModel) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

        // Showing selected spinner item
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + item.getCityName(), 
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
```

Adapter class

```
public class CityAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CitiesModel> {


    public CityAdapter(@NonNull Context context,@NonNull int textviewId,@NonNull List<CitiesModel> cities)
    {
        super(context,0,textviewId,cities);
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView,@NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        CitiesModel rowItem = getItem(position);

        View rowview = convertView;

        if(rowview == null)
            rowview = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.city_row,parent,false);


  //          CheckBox cityCheck = (CheckBox) rowview.findViewById(R.id.citychk);
            TextView cityTitle = (TextView) rowview.findViewById(R.id.citytitle);
  //          cityCheck.setChecked(rowItem.isChecked());
            cityTitle.setText(rowItem.getCityName());

            return rowview;
    }



}
```

Comment: have you tried toString() method?

Comment: The value you set on the `rowView` is not a `String`. Check the return type of `CitiesModel#getCityName()`.

Comment: Dear Deepak getCityName() is returning String for your information here is the code of getCityName.


    public String getCityName() {
        return cityName;
    }

    public void setCityName(String cityName) {
        this.cityName = cityName;
    }